# Custom sort function for a Javascript Array works in Chrome Console but not React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

So this is an extremely weird issue. I have the following sorting function:

```
  sortByKey(array, key) {
    console.log(array, key)
    return array.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x = a[key]; var y = b[key];
        return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
    });
  }
```

which basically just sorts a Javascript Object by the specified key.

When I pass an array and key into it manually (in the console), it does what it's expected to do and sorts the array in descending order.

However, calling it inside React, it actually doesn't sort anything, the logged result isn't sorted at all and I'm at my wits end trying to figure out what's happening.

Below is the react code I'm using

```
parsedResults.push({
  position: position,
  results: tempResultsObj
})
console.log(this.sortByKey(this.parsedResults[index].results, "count"))
```

Any idea why this function works in console but not in React? I honestly have no idea.

Comment: I noticed that when attempting sorting, despite the array being sorted (printing a JSON Stringified version), the Chromium console automatically sorts objects and arrays alphabetically. I have no proof or anything on this, its purely theoretical, but I noticed this once while constructing a `sort` function. Try using a `Set` instead of an array. They're designed for persistent order.

Comment: Can you link to a sandbox demoing the issue? I'm not able to reproduce the problem when I try using the sort in a React sandbox.